# how to write a test for below component in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

could you please help me in writing the test for below component?

```
import { string, node } from "prop-types"

import * as Styled from "./Banner.styled"

const Banner = ({ heading, button }) => (
  <Styled.Banner>
    <Styled.Heading>{heading}</Styled.Heading>
    {button && button}
  </Styled.Banner>
)

Banner.propTypes = {
  heading: string.isRequired,
  button: node,
}

Banner.defaultProps = {
  button: null,
}

export default Banner
```

I need to write a test in react library to see if the imported component(button) in rendering.

Could you please help me ? I tried the following but I think this is wrong :) The first test passes, but the second for the button itself is wrong:(

```
import { render, screen } from "../../../test-utils"

import Banner from "../Banner"

const heading = "heading"
const button = "button"

describe(`Banner`, () => {
  it(`renders Banner with default properties`, () => {
    render(<Banner heading={heading} />)
    expect(screen.getByText(heading)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
  it(`renders Banner with default properties`, () => {
    render(<Banner button={button} />)
    expect(screen.getByText(button)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Comment: Better to pass a button and then check. Do not jsut pass text

Comment: what do you mean by passing the button? Should I use different method?

Answer (score 0):

The second test case fails because your `Banner` expects `heading` props as ***required***.

```js
describe(`Banner`, () => {
  it(`renders Banner without default properties`, () => {
    render(<Banner heading={heading} />)
    expect(screen.getByText(heading)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
  it(`renders Banner with default properties`, () => {
    render(<Banner heading={heading} button={button} />)
    expect(screen.getByText(button)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Try giving `heading` props in the second one.

Comment: Hi, I tried thi and it does not work :(describe(`Banner`, () => {
  it(`renders Banner with default properties`, () => {
    render(<Banner heading={heading} />)
    expect(screen.getByText(heading)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
  it(`renders Banner with default properties`, () => {
    render(<Banner heading={heading} />)
    expect(screen.getByText(button)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})

Comment: I think the point is that it is the button that needs to be tested not heading